# Tensorflow OutOfRange Error

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, machine-learning, tfrecord

**My Code is to read image from tfrecord file**

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data_path='christmas.tfrecords'

with tf.Session() as sess:
    feature={'image':tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),'label':tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64)}
    # Create a list of filenames and pass it to a queue
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path], num_epochs=1)
    # Define a reader and read the next record
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    # Decode the record read by the reader
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)
    # Convert the image data from string back to the numbers
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image'], tf.float32)

    # Cast label data into int32
    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
    # Reshape image data into the original shape
    image = tf.reshape(image, [224, 224, 1])

    # Any preprocessing here ...

    # Creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors
    images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=10, capacity=30, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=10)

    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op)
    # Create a coordinator and run all QueueRunner objects
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for batch_index in range(5):
        img, lbl = sess.run([images, labels])
        img = img.astype(np.uint8)
        for j in range(6):
            plt.subplot(2, 3, j+1)
            plt.imshow(img[j, ...])
            plt.title('cat' if lbl[j]==0 else 'dog')
        plt.show()
    # Stop the threads
    coord.request_stop()

    # Wait for threads to stop
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

**Error Message**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 10, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_tfrecords.py", line 35, in <module>
    img, lbl = sess.run([images, labels])
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 10, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]

Caused by op 'shuffle_batch', defined at:
  File "read_tfrecords.py", line 27, in <module>
    images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=10, capacity=30, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=10)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 1225, in shuffle_batch
    name=name)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 796, in _shuffle_batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 464, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 2418, in _queue_dequeue_many_v2
    component_types=component_types, timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/robinreni/Documents/pythonprojects/cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 10, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]
```

I converted all the image and labels to tfrecord file and have to convert the file to raw image and label during training. I am trying to read the image from the tfrecords but the outofrange error pops up. Please anyone help how to fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OutOfRangeError` raises because the `shapes` are not specified:

`images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=10, capacity=30, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=10, shapes=[[224, 224, 1], []])`

should work.

See documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch)